# On Heroku server media files getting deleted automatically after sometimes of deployment of web application

Tags: heroku, django-models, django-forms, http-post, http-get

I am surprised, after successful deployment of a Django web application on heroku server.

I am able to view the media files just after the deployment but after sometimes i am unable to view it.

Error : GET https://mysite.herokuapp.com/media/files/testing_pphTYTV.mp4 404 (Not Found)
suggestions to resolve this is appreciated.....

i have used following line of code.

In settings.py file:

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: See https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted - don't use the local file system on a PaaS.